# Count the values for each aggregated data time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Im trying to aggregate datetime by hours and count the values.

Here is sample dataframe :

```
   date_time
1/1/10 18:28:54 +0100 #format %d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S %z
1/1/10 18:29:12 +0100
1/1/10 19:27:50 +0100
1/2/10 20:25:06 +0100
```

I need this:

```
date_time   count
1/1/10 18     2
1/1/10 19     1
1/2/10 20     1
```

Here my code:

```
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_3xx.date_time)
df_3xx = df_3xx.groupby([times.hour]).count()
```

What I have:

```
ValueError: Array must be all same time zone
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

We can try:

```
new_df = (df.assign(date_time = df['date_time'].astype(str).str[:9])
            .groupby('date_time').size().reset_index(name='count'))
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
   date_time  count
0  1/1/10 18      2
1  1/1/10 19      1
2  1/2/10 20      1
```

Comment: There is not the hours displayed, is the str[:9] realy reliable ? Then I can use str[:13]

Comment: str: 9 shows until the hours, str: 13 would show until the minutes, you can see it in the dataframe that it showed, but if in any case you need to group by the minutes you can also use str [: 13]